# Can not by conda install scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

when I install scrapy, the errors occur.

error on below:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed  

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - scrapy -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

my command: conda install -n virtualenv -c conda-forge scrapy

please help me resolve, thank you very much.

Comment: you need to specify python to 3.9, check the error message properly

Comment: Do you have a package or environment.yml file? @laokong

Comment: Hi @auvipy, How to  specify python to 3.9 by command, like this?             `conda install -n virtualenv -c conda-forge scrapy python=3.9`